# Create PDF File From Android Native Views

Tags: java, android, pdf

In our android application we have photo album capabilities. Which users are able to create their albums from their photos and after that we want users to be able to create a pdf file from that albums.(We are doing the same thing in IOS)

For achiving this, I've implemented the below solution. But when I executed the createPrintableFile method it creates and empty pdf file and I couldnt find why? 
Does anyone have any idea about it

```
package com.kidokit.kidokit.helper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.print.PrintAttributes;
import android.print.pdf.PrintedPdfDocument;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kidokit.kidokit.R;
import com.kidokit.kidokit.network.NetworkModels;
import com.kidokit.kidokit.ui.StorybookView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;





public class MAPdfCreator
{
    private FileOutputStream pdfFile = null;
    private String filePath = null;
    private Activity act;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MAPdfCreator(Activity act) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        filePath = act.getFilesDir()+"/KidoKitAlbum.pdf";
        pdfFile = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        this.act = act;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.act);
    }

    public void createPrintableFile(List<NetworkModels.GetPhotosInAlbumRes.Photo> photos) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<View> result = new ArrayList<View>();

        int index = 0;
        for (NetworkModels.GetPhotosInAlbumRes.Photo photo : photos) {
            View myImageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_storybook, null, false);
            final StorybookView sbv = (StorybookView) myImageLayout.findViewById(R.id.sbv);
            sbv.measure(480,853);
            sbv.layout(0,0,480,853);

            if (index == 0) {
                /*
                sbv.setTemplateLayout(R.layout.view_sb_cover);
                sbv.setImage(photo.photoFile);
                sbv.setLabel(photo.photoTitle);
                sbv.setDate(photo.photoDate);
                sbv.closeEditMode();
                */
            } else {
                sbv.setTemplateLayout(photo.getLayoutResource());

                if (photo.photoFile != null && !photo.photoFile.equals("")) {
                    sbv.setImage(photo.photoFile);
                }
                if (photo.photoTitle != null) {
                    sbv.setLabel(photo.photoTitle);
                }

                if (photo.photoDate != null) {
                    sbv.setDate(photo.photoDate);
                }
                sbv.closeEditMode();


            }

            result.add(sbv);
            index++;
        }

        convertViewsToPdf(result);
    }

    public void convertViewsToPdf(ArrayList<View> views) throws IOException {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {

            PrintAttributes printAttrs = new PrintAttributes.Builder().
                    setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR).
                    setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_LETTER).
                    setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("KDK_LBL", "PRINT_SERVICE", 480, 853)).
                    setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS).
                    build();
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();


            int index = 0;
            for (View view : views) {
                PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(480,853,index).create();
                PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

                view.draw(page.getCanvas());

                document.finishPage(page);
                index++;
            }

            document.writeTo(pdfFile);


            document.close();
            pdfFile.close();



            File file = new File(filePath);
            if(!file.exists()) {
                System.out.println("FILE DOES NOT EXIST");
                return;
            }

            this.openPdfFile();
        }
    }

    public void openPdfFile()
    {
        Uri path = Uri.parse("content://"+act.getPackageName()+"/"+filePath);

        Intent fileViewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        fileViewIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        String packageName = "com.adobe.reader";

        fileViewIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        fileViewIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        try {
            act.startActivity(fileViewIntent);

        } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){

            try {
                act.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+packageName)));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                act.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+packageName)));
            }

        } catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(act, "Can not open file: (" + filePath +")", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the code which calls the abow createPrintableFile method

```
private void printAlbum(final int albumId)
{
    NetworkManager.getPhotosInAlbum(albumId,new TokenCallback<NetworkModels.GetPhotosInAlbumRes>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<NetworkModels.GetPhotosInAlbumRes> call, Response<NetworkModels.GetPhotosInAlbumRes> response) {
            super.onResponse(call, response);

            if (response.code() == 200) {
                if (response.body().success) {

                    NetworkModels.GetPhotosInAlbumRes result = response.body();
                    try {
                        MAPdfCreator creator = new MAPdfCreator(currrentContext);
                        creator.createPrintableFile(result.photos);
                    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    activity.progressDialog.dismiss();
                    activity.showSnackbar(activity.getText(R.string.unknown_error).toString());
                }
            } else {
                activity.showSnackbar(activity.getText(R.string.server_error).toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<NetworkModels.GetPhotosInAlbumRes> call, Throwable t) {
            super.onFailure(call, t);
            activity.showSnackbar(activity.getText(R.string.connection_error).toString());
            activity.progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling convertViewsToPdf, are the views still alive?

Comment: PS index is supposed to start from 1, not zero

Comment: I've updated the code which calls the cratePdfFile method

Comment: Have you tried to debug by writing the views to jpeg files?

Comment: Try to do that and see whether there will be anything in the images